# GTK FileChooserDialog Crashes my script

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am using GTK FileChooserDialog(gtk 2.14, pygtk 2.12) to create a dialog inside my IDE via python(2.5.2) scripts.

In my python script I have created following class.

```
class GTKFileDialog():
    def __init__(self, *extension):
        self.Selector = gtk.FileChooserDialog("dqfs", None, action=gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, buttons=(gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,gtk.STOCK_OPEN,gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
        self.Selector.set_default_response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK)
        self.Selector.set_current_folder(os.getcwd())
        self.filter = gtk.FileFilter()
        for ext in extensions:
            self.filter.add_pattern(ext)
        self.Selector.add_filter(self.filter)
        # GTK button to finish the operation of selection
        Button = gtk.Button("Select")
        self.Selector.add_action_widget(Button, 10)
        Button.show()        
    def run(self):
        # Run the Selector object 
        out = self.Selector.run()
        filename = None
        if out == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            filename = self.Selector.get_filename()
        self.Selector.destroy()
        # return the selected filename
        return filename
```

Now whenever I try to create object for this class, my python script crashes and IDE closes down.

```
    ChooseFile = GTKFileDialog(".png")
    ChooseFile.run()
```

I cant even know what exception it is raising. I am sure it doesnot execute the `run` function. I tried using try/except but that did not work. Can any body tell me what I am doing wrong?
Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What is your `class GTKFileSelector` supposed to inherit from? I suspect you meant something more like `class MyFileSelector(GTKFileSelector)`?

Comment: @WiData: Works for me. "whenever I try to create object for this class, my python script crashes and IDE closes down" --- ever heard of running from console?

Comment: @ali_m: It is not supposed to inherit. I am using this class to create multiple instances of the file selector window.

Comment: @doublep: The script is being run by IDE. Even if I run the script by Console it does not work from me.

Comment: Anyone, Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to destroy the dialog in `run()`, try `self.Selector.hide()` instead and see what happens...

Comment: thanks for the inputs. But I already tried this one. No difference.